# Rails Routing based on Parameters

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, routes

I am working on a Rails app, and I am looking for a way to route to different actions in the controller based on the existence of parameters in the url.

For example I want `website.com/model` to route to `model#index`, however I want `website.com/model?opt=dev` to route to `model#show`. Is there some way this can be done?

Comment: I believe you can use the `:constraints` option to get this behavior.  
Documentation: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#segment-constraints.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use route constraints to look at the request object and see if it has URL parameters.  If you're using restful routes, you want to put this "one-off" before the restful route.  Something like this:

```
get 'users' => 'users#show', constraints: { query_string: /.+/ }
resources :users
```

So what this is saying is that if you request "/users?opt=dev" then it will match your special case.  Otherwise, it falls through to your normal restful route to the index action.  Your model#show action will then have to know to pick up the param[:opt] and do whatever with it.

Also, note that the regex is very loose and it's simply checking for ANY param...you'll want to tighten that up to fit whatever you're trying to do.

Comment: Ah, good answer. I had gotten as far as trying to use constraints, but I didn't know about the query_string. What is contained in this? How can I use this to look for specific things such as `opt` or other options. My use case requires me to distinguish between different things such as `opt`, `email`, etc.

Comment: The query_string is part of the [request object](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#the-request-object).  It's literally everything after the "?" in the URL.  The example I posted is, like I said, is using a very general regex.  If you need more logic than a simple regex, I'd probably put this in the controller and not the routes for maintainability reasons.

Answer (score 1):

Not strictly the same, but if you came to this post and were wondering how to do the same via a POST, then you can do it based on the request_paramters.

for your routes.rb ..

```
module MyConstraintName  
extend self
  def matches?(request)
    request.request_parameters["routeFlag"] == "routeToModelShow"
  end
end

match "pages/:id", :via=>:post, :controller=>"model", :action=>"show",  :constraints => MyConstraintName
```

and in your form for example..

```
<%= hidden_field_tag :routeFlag, "routeToModelShow" %>
```